# How to upgrade the hibernate-validator 4.3.0.Final to the Glassfish 3.1.2?

Tags: glassfish-3, hibernate-validator

At the moment, the Hibernate Validator has released the latest version as 4.3.0.Final [here](http://bit.ly/KPJvw9). I have tried to upgrade it to my Glassfish 3.1.2 as the following step: -

```
1. Remove the GLASSFISH/glassfish/modules/bean-validator.jar
2. Copying the hibernate-validator-4.3.0.Final.jar to GLASSFISH/glassfish/modules
3. Restart the Glassfish
4. The Glassfish cannot start. It seems hang.
```

After searching via the Google, I've found that the file named "bean-validator.jar" was created by the Glassfish team as an OSGi version. Sadly, I cannot find how to create it. Could you please help to advise further? Thank you very much for your help in advance. I'm looking forward to hearing from you soon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A (slightly outdated) description of how to build Glassfish's bean-validator.jar can be found [here](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/GlassFish/V3Jsr303BeanValidationIntegration).

What's needed in general is an OSGi bundle which includes Hibernate Validator itself and the Bean Validation API. With this bundle you should be able to replace the original bean-validator.jar. Additionally you need the JBoss Logging bundle, which is used since release 4.3 by Hibernate Validator as logging API and already comes in form of an OSGi bundle.

If you're building a web application, you could also package HV 4.3 within your WAR and [turn off](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beaft.html#beagb) class loader delegation by providing the file `WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml` with the following contents:

```
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app>
    <class-loader delegate="false" />
</glassfish-web-app>
```

That way the HV classes will be loaded from your application instead of from the module provided by Glassfish.

You might also be interested in the issue [GLASSFISH-15648](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-15648) which aims to provide a dedicated Glassfish update package for HV.

Comment: Thank you very much for you kindly explanation. I would like to ask for your help further as I'm building the EJB project. The glassfish-ejb-jar does not has the "class-loader" property configuration. Could you please help to explain further?

Comment: The suggested configuration of the class loader delegation unfortunately works only within WARs, so you probably would have to create a custom OSGi bundle.

Comment: @Gunnar I tried turning off the delegated class loader in my WAR file and including hibernate-validator 4.3.0.Final dependency but now I am stuck with the problem that although glassfish finds it that when my startup ejb runs i get the following `WEB9031: WebappClassLoader unable to load resource [org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorContextImpl], because it has not yet been started, or was already stopped`

Comment: This (packaging the 4.3.0.Final hibernate jar inside the war, and adding the aforementioned glassfish-web.xml) worked for me, at least for my war file. Thanks Gunnar!

Answer (score 3):

As my case was `ear`, rather than `war`, based on suggestion of Gunnar, I did a patched version of the module, that is deployable to `Glassfish` (My version is `3.1.1 OSE`).

Someone might find it still useful, see my blog for my solution (including step-by-step approach): http://peter-butkovic.blogspot.de/2012/11/glassfish-311-oss-with-hibernate.html