# Using hibernate-validator with javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final) and glassfish-embedded-all?

Tags: java, validation, glassfish

I am using the Glassfish library like this in my webapp to be in sync with Glassfish embedded libs directory during development. How can I update it to be able to use javax.validation.api 1.1.0?
This is the glassfish dependency:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
 <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
 <version>4.0-b72</version>
 <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Unfortunately this glassfish lib collection is still using an older javax.validation-api lib. But to use:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
 <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
 <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

I need a newer one. Is there any way to update the Glassfish libs if there isn't a new version for glassfish-embedded-all.
How do you solve such issues?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to update the Glassfish libs **if there isn't a new
>   version** for glassfish-embedded-all.

Yes, but there is also a new version which is the 4.0 final build of GlassFish.

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
 <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
 <version>4.0</version>
 <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

This version includes `Hibernate Validator 5.0.0` which already depends on `Validation API 1.1.0`.

If you need a newer version then `Hibernate Validator 5.0.0` you have to extract the corresponding GlassFish module (in this case `bean-validation.jar`), change the `pom.xml` to depend on the desired version and rebuild it with `mvn package`.

**See also:**

- [Bean-Validation 1.1 in Glassfish 4.0 - CDI Injection not working as intended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19925540/bean-validation-1-1-in-glassfish-4-0-cdi-injection-not-working-as-intended)
- [Trouble starting Hibernate Validator due to Bean Validation API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21656146/trouble-starting-hibernate-validator-due-to-bean-validation-api)
- [How to upgrade the hibernate-validator 4.3.0.Final to the Glassfish 3.1.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548931/how-to-upgrade-the-hibernate-validator-4-3-0-final-to-the-glassfish-3-1-2)