# Update hibernate-validator in glassfish4

Tags: glassfish-4, hibernate-validator, java-ee-7

Glassfish-ApplicationServer comes with a bean-validator.jar, which itself includes / was built with hibernator-validator 5.0.0.Final

```
// From glassfish4-startup:
2014-05-13T14:49:37.260+0200|Information: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.0.Final
```

I want use another version of hibernate-valditor. How can I achieve this?

**What happened so far..**

Glassfish4-source is available at [svn.java.net](https://svn.java.net/svn/glassfish~svn/branches/4.0/), but I cannot find anything close to a package "bean-validator". The only thing mentionable is [nucleus/core/kernel/src/main/java/org/glassfish/kernel/bean_validator/](https://svn.java.net/svn/glassfish~svn/branches/4.0/nucleus/core/kernel/src/main/java/org/glassfish/kernel/bean_validator/), but that seem's to be a dead end.

Stackoverflow-Question [How to upgrade the hibernate-validator 4.3.0.Final to the Glassfish 3.1.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548931/how-to-upgrade-the-hibernate-validator-4-3-0-final-to-the-glassfish-3-1-2) brings us to a good blog-article http://peter-butkovic.blogspot.de/2012/11/glassfish-311-oss-with-hibernate.html. In this blog-article, [svn.java.net/svn/hk2~svn/branches/hk2-gf-3.1.1/](https://svn.java.net/svn/hk2~svn/branches/hk2-gf-3.1.1/) is mentioned. I don't know what that is, or where something similar for glassfish4 is.

Answer (score 1):

You may refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548931/how-to-upgrade-the-hibernate-validator-4-3-0-final-to-the-glassfish-3-1-2) as a starting point.

It's not 100% up-to-date though as it applies to Hibernate Validator 4.3. But actually I'd expect the update from 5.0 to 5.1 to be even easier as no new dependencies have been added, so you'd basically have to update the OSGi bundle from Glassfish with the latest HV JAR (and update the manifest to export the new "valuehandling" package if you want to make use of this feature).

Comment: I had found that question already, but did not manage to migrate it to glassfish4. In special, I did not find any similar to svn.java.net/svn/hk2~svn/branches/hk2-gf-3.1.1/. Can you tell me, what "hk2" is?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://svn.java.net/svn/glassfish~svn/trunk/external/modules/bean-validator/), this should build the bean-validator.jar. You might try to adapt this to the HV version you want to use. I'd be very interested in the outcome.